# cakephp multiple association to the same model save problems

Tags: cakephp

I have model Transaction that is linked to Customer twice with sender_id and recipient_id foreign keys respectively

```
public $belongTo = array(
    'Sender' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'sender_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Recipient' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ) 
)
```

Which data keys must the customer data be placed in order to be saved? I have tried this.

```
$data['Transaction']['amount'];
$data['Recipient']['name'];
$data['Sender']['name'];
```

Recipient and Sender aliasing Customer model.

Now the big quetion. Do the Recipient and Sender aliases resolve to Customer on save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your data format is correct. You just need to use saveAll or saveAssociated on the Transaction model.

See the [Cookbook for a description of saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array). It is actually a wrapper which will determine whether it needs to do a saveAssociated(), which it would in your case, or a saveMany(), which saves multiple records to the same model.

```
$this->Transaction->saveAll($data);
```

If you're performing edits on the Transaction model, be sure to include the Recipient.id and Sender.id in the form and they will be updated instead of creating new records.

Comment: my concern was with the Customer aliases . calling saveAll() in transaction appeared to me as trying to save more than two associations in one shot. a feature am not aware . please correct me there.

Comment: saveAll() will save date in each model included in the passed data. In your case it will save the Transaction amount, the Recipient name, and the Sender name. Recipient and Sender would save to the customers table.

Comment: thanks man. finally got it. i can't upvote you because my reputation value

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty with my CakePHP but I believe the answer to your question is yes.

To save a sender you would have:

```
$this->Sender->save();
```

Instead of:

```
$this->Customer->save();
```

Comment: $this->Sender->save() will be called from where. Transaction or Customer model. Also will calling saveAll() in Transaction model save aliased associations correctly